# Performance/Memory Problems when porting PyTorch Code to TensorFlow (GPU)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to port an operation that uses convolutional kernels to transform time series for further tasks (e.g. classification, etc).
The following code is written in PyTorch and is intended for use on GPU:

```
class ROCKET(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c_in, seq_len, n_kernels=10_000, kss=[7, 9, 11], device=None, verbose=False):
        super().__init__()
        device = ifnone(device, default_device())
        kss = [ks for ks in kss if ks < seq_len]
        convs = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(n_kernels):
            ks = np.random.choice(kss)
            dilation = 2**np.random.uniform(0, np.log2((seq_len - 1) // (ks - 1)))
            padding = int((ks - 1) * dilation // 2) if np.random.randint(2) == 1 else 0
            weight = torch.randn(1, c_in, ks)
            weight -= weight.mean()
            bias = 2 * (torch.rand(1) - .5)
            layer = nn.Conv1d(c_in, 1, ks, padding=2 * padding, dilation=int(dilation), bias=True)
            layer.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(weight, requires_grad=False)
            layer.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(bias, requires_grad=False)
            convs.append(layer)
        self.convs = convs
        self.n_kernels = n_kernels
        self.kss = kss
        self.to(device=device)
        self.verbose=verbose

    def forward(self, x):
        _output = []
        for i in progress_bar(range(self.n_kernels), display=self.verbose, leave=False, comment='kernel/kernels'):
            out = self.convs[i](x).cpu()
            _max = out.max(dim=-1)[0]
            _ppv = torch.gt(out, 0).sum(dim=-1).float() / out.shape[-1]
            _output.append(_max)
            _output.append(_ppv)
        return torch.cat(_output, dim=1)
```

My approach in tensorflow (GPU) so far looks like this and performs the same computations:

```
from tqdm import trange
class ROCKET():
    def __init__(self, c_in, seq_len, n_kernels = 10_000, kss=[7,9,11]):
        kss = [ks for ks in kss if ks < seq_len]
        weights = []
        biases = []
        dilations = []
        for i in (t := trange(n_kernels)):
            ks = np.random.choice(kss)
            dilation = 2**np.random.uniform(0, np.log2((seq_len - 1) // (ks - 1)))

            weight = tf.random.normal([ks,c_in,1], dtype=tf.double)
            weight -= tf.math.reduce_mean(weight)
            weight = tf.Variable(weight)
        
            bias = tf.Variable(2 * (tf.random.normal([1], dtype=tf.double) - .5), dtype=tf.double)
            
            weights.append(weight)
            biases.append(bias)
            dilations.append(dilation)
            
            t.set_description("set kernels") 
            
        self.weights = weights
        self.biases = biases
        self.dilations = dilations
        self.n_kernels = n_kernels
        
    
    def forward(self, x):
        _output = []
        for i in (t := trange(self.n_kernels)):
            weight = self.weights[i]
            bias = self.biases[i]
            dilation = self.dilations[i]
            
            tensor = tf.nn.conv1d(x, filters=weight, stride=1, padding='VALID', dilations=dilation)
            tensor = tf.nn.bias_add(tensor, bias)
    
            _max = tf.Variable(tf.math.reduce_max(tensor, axis=-1))

            temp = tf.cast(tf.math.greater(tensor, 0), tf.double)
            _ppv = tf.math.reduce_sum(temp, axis=-1) / tensor.shape[-1]
    
            _output.append(_max)
            _output.append(_ppv)
            
            t.set_description("apply kernels")
            
        return tf.concat(_output, axis=1)
```

However, this approach performs much slower (30secs for just the constructor).

Further, since my GPU quickly runs out of memory (6GB VRAM), I can only use it on small datasets.

Are there some immediate performance benefits I am missing out on?
I also noticed that the computations are performed by my CPU and just stored in GPU memory.

Would it be beneficial to use tf.placeholders?

Comment: It's a super open question, not the best fit for stackoverflow. My advices are: don't use `tf.Variable` in the forward (you don't need it anyway), use tf.float32 instead of tf.double, and give a look to @tf.function.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

so I managed to solve my problem. Turns out, I just had the wrong data_format. I thought default format for tf.nn.conv1d is 'NCW', as in the PyTorch implementation of the layer (it's the opposite actually).
Constructor calling took so long because of tqdm... (now its the expected ~1sec).

Finally, here is the working code:

```
from tqdm import trange
class ROCKET():
    def __init__(self, c_in, seq_len, n_kernels = 10_000, kss=[7,9,11]):
        kss = [ks for ks in kss if ks < seq_len]
        weights = []
        biases = []
        dilations = []
        for i in range(n_kernels):
            ks = np.random.choice(kss)
            dilation = 2**np.random.uniform(0, np.log2((seq_len - 1) // (ks - 1)))
            
            #NCW
            weight = tf.random.normal([ks,c_in,1], dtype=tf.float32)
            weight -= tf.math.reduce_mean(weight)
        
            bias = 2 * (tf.random.normal([1], dtype=tf.float32) - .5)
            
            weights.append(weight)
            biases.append(bias)
            dilations.append(dilation)
            
        self.weights = weights
        self.biases = biases
        self.dilations = dilations
        self.n_kernels = n_kernels

    #@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.float32)])
    def apply_kernels(self, x):
        _output = []
        for i in (t := trange(self.n_kernels)):
            #ks = self.ks[i]
            bias = self.biases[i]
            dilation = self.dilations[i]
            weight = self.weights[i]
            
            
            tensor = tf.nn.conv1d(x, filters=weight, stride=1, padding='VALID', data_format='NCW', dilations=dilation)
            tensor = tf.nn.bias_add(tensor, bias, data_format='NCW')
    
            _max = tf.math.reduce_max(tensor, axis=-1)

            temp = tf.cast(tf.math.greater(tensor, 0), tf.float32)
            _ppv = tf.math.reduce_sum(temp, axis=-1) / tensor.shape[-1]

            _output.append(_max)
            _output.append(_ppv)
            
            t.set_description("apply kernels")
        
        return tf.concat(_output, axis=1)
```

Thanks to @Lescurel I also managed to improve the performance by removing tf.Variables.